# open Command Prompt and execute commands from Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working with sockets , server is Windows form app and client is an android app. I am sending commands commands through client and want to execute those commands on server , i want to open command prompt and execute those commands received from client and show response in textBox on server side but when I run my apps the windows form app opens again when Command Prompt is to be opened and command is to be executed.

Here is my function that handles the request received from android client

```
   private void HandleMsg(String s)
    {
      if (s == "SS")
        {
            STW.WriteLine("SendingImage");
            SendScreenToClient();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Process myprocess = new Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"; // starts cmd window
                StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // required to redirect
                StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; // <---- creates no window, obviously
                myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo;
                myprocess.Start();
                System.IO.StreamReader SR = myprocess.StandardOutput;
                System.IO.StreamWriter SW = myprocess.StandardInput;
                SW.WriteLine(s); // the command you wish to run.....
                SW.WriteLine("exit"); // exits command prompt window
                textBox3.Text = SR.ReadToEnd(); // returns results of the command window
                SW.Close();
                SR.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception E) { MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());}
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) and specifically the [`System.Management`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management?view=netframework-4.8) interface. See an example in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-#systemmanagement-example).

You can then use something like:

```cs
var wProcess = new ManagementClass(wScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
wProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", new[] { "cmd.exe" });
```

Comment: I have solved the issue, i am running commands through app but while reading the output It reads entire window of CMD as **ReadToEnd()** is being used, I want to read only the result of command, Do you have any Idea How can I do this ?